# @nbsp is not working with php databse value

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my larvel project adm showing my email form php database,,but the problem is that i want to add a single space  after `Email:`. Now it is displaying as `Email:test@testmail.com` and i want to make it as `Email: test@testmail.com`.

Following is my code

```
<div id="details_email" class="details_email">Email:@nbsp<a href="mailto:'+clinicemail+'">'+clinicemail +'</a></div>'
```

In this code `clinicemail` will display the value from php database. I have added `@nbsp`,but its not working.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no blade syntax as `@nbsp` in laravel so, 
Change your `@nbsp` to `&nbsp;` to make it work

Comment: @EdisonDeckward please stop asking people to upvote your question. They would do so, _if_ they thought this was one that deserved an upvote to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no entity such as `@nbsp` in HTML change your code to `&nbsp`.